# Is Visual Basic (based on the NET Framework) a dying language?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I see more and more job postings about C# and C#. Are most VB NET programmers moving to C#? Are there any enterprise class applications (whether Windows or Web-based) still being written in Visual Basic?

Comment: No intention on causing any arguments but I can see how the question can start an argument.

Comment: this probably should have been migrated to programmers.stackexchange.com instead of just being outright closed.

Comment: People have been asking me "is VB dying" for *fifteen years*. VB was in no danger of "dying out" fifteen years ago, and it certainly is not now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. ASP.NET development, for instance, has a strong VB.NET following. I haven't seen any decline in this in recent years, from my personal experience.